# Loading Image from Firebase Storage using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

`

Hello I'm trying to load some images from Firebase Storage using downloadUrl but it always crashes and I don't know why I already set up rules in the storage but it still doesn't work

I added these dependencies

> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx'
> implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.2')

My code is this:

```
`var storageRef = Firebase.storage.reference.child("post/$uId/$fileName.png") //I want to load image from a certain user

var imageUri:String?=null

storageRef.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { Uri->
    imageUri=Uri.toString() 
}
-.addOnFailureListener {
    Toast.makeText(this@UploadActivity, it.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() 
}`
```

Basically when debugging it doesn't enter addOnSuccessListener nor addOnfailureLister and imageUri remains null even though I can see that downloadUrl has translated the gs://... to https://firebase...

I also added these rules indise my firebase Storage

```
`rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that it may take time to fetch the Image from Firebase storage and before you get the Image from firebase storage you try to load the Image in ImageView and the app crashes because the Uri is still null.
Try

```
 Firebase.storage.reference.child("post/$uId/$fileName.png").
    downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { Uri->
         Glide.with(YOUR_ACTIVITY_CONTEXT).
         load(Uri.toString()).
         into(YOUR_IMAGE_VIEW)
    }
    -.addOnFailureListener {
        Toast.makeText(this@UploadActivity, it.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() 
    }`
```

[For detailed knowledge of Glide Library here is the link](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)